# Awesomium 1.7.5 webView.ExecuteJavascript not work

Tags: .net, awesomium, off-screen

I used Offscreen browser. Then, I created `webView`, subscribed to `DocumentReady` and loaded html.

```
_originalWebView = WebCore.CreateWebView(this.ViewWidth, this.ViewHeight, WebViewType.Offscreen);
_originalWebView.DocumentReady += browser_DocumentReady;
_originalWebView.LoadHTML(html);
```

My method for `DocumentReady`:

```
private void browser_DocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    var webView = sender as WebView;
    if (webView == null)
        return;

    if (e.ReadyState == DocumentReadyState.Ready)
        return;

    var global = e.Environment;

    if (!global)
        return;

    webView.ExecuteJavascript(@"
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'Hello World' ;
");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    if (webView.GetLastError() != Error.None)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("There was an error calling this synchronous method");

    Html = _originalWebView.HTML;
    webView.Dispose();
}
```

My html:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id='id'>old value</div>
      </body>
</html>
```

And this javascript didn't work. What did I do wrong?
I can did it to execute js only if js was in html. I used Awesomium 1.7.5. 
Help me, please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved when i replaced

```
Html = _originalWebView.HTML;
```

on

```
Html = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void WebViewOnDocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    var webView = sender as WebControl;
    webView.ExecuteJavascript(@"document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'Hello World';");
}
```